# What does the "&" symbol do in a callback function like this one?

Tags: php, function, callback

I am wondering what the "&" sign does in this callback function.

```
array_walk($array, function (& $item) {
   $item['new_key'] = $item['old_key'];
   unset($item['old_key']);
});
```

Comment: It indicates 'pass by value'.

Comment: [Reference to `$item`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php). This means that the original variable `$item` will reflect any changes that occur to it within that callback.